# Why $f(0)\neq 0$ where $f $ is a polynomial over the field $\mathbb F_q$ and $\deg(f)=m > 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

> To construct the residue class ring $\mathbb F_q[x]/(f)$ having $q^m-1$ non-zero elements is it necessary for $f(0) \neq 0$? Why or why not?

I have worked with different examples such as $x^3+x=f \in F_2[x]$ but could not find why $f(0) \neq 0$ is necessary for residue class ring $F_q[x]/(f)$.

Comment: It's necessary for $f$ to be irreducible, which in particular means that $f(0)\ne0$.

Comment: But all polynomials of degree 1 are irreducible i.e. $f=cx$ where $c$ is non-zero so $f(0)=0$

Comment: The quotient ring $F_q[x]/(f)$ will, indeed, have $q^m-1$ non-zero elements whenever $\deg f=m$. However, if $f(0)=0$ and $m>1$, then $x\mid f(x)$ and the quotient ring will have zero divisors. May be that is unwanted?

Comment: I was assuming you meant $m>1$, since the quotient $F[x]/(ax+b)$ (for any field $F$ and any $a\ne 0$) is just isomorphic to $F$ again.